# Use types in <cstdint> with or without namespace

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

In C++11 I can choose whether I want to use the types defined in  with or without the namespace std::

At least my compiler (g++ 4.7) accepts both variants.

My question is: What is the recommended way to use the typedefs from cstdint. With or without the namespace? What are the advantages or disadvantages? Or is it only a matter of style?

so variant a):

```
#include <cstdint>
std::uint8_t n = 21;
```

resp:

```
#include <cstdint>
using std::uint8_t;
uint8_t n = 21;
```

or variant b):

```
#include <cstdint>
uint8_t n = 21;
```

Comment: I think C++11 removed the restruction of the C stuff being in `std`.

Comment: I think you meant "std::" in your first example, not "std:"

Comment: I would use `#include <stdint.h>  uint8_t n = 21;`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Prefer names declared in the `std` namespace. The reason is given in §17.6.1.3/4 (*ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)*, C++11):

> Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents of each header *cname* shall be the same as that of the corresponding header *name*`.h`, as specified in the C standard library (1.2) or the C Unicode TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace `std`. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace `std` by explicit *using-declarations* (7.3.3).

If you use the names from the `<c`*name*`>` headers without `std`, your program is relying on unspecified requirements.

This was different in C++03 and earlier where names were only supposed to appear in the `std` namespace. However, the reality was that many implementations were simply injecting the contents of the C standard library headers `<`*name*`.h>` into `std` and so this was accommodated for in C++11. The corresponding section (§17.4.1.2/4) from the C++03 standard says:

> Except as noted in clauses 18 through 27, the contents of each header *cname* shall be the same as that of the corresponding header *name*`.h`, as specified in ISO/IEC 9899:1990 Programming Languages C (Clause 7), or ISO/IEC:1990 Programming Languages—C AMENDMENT 1: C Integrity, (Clause 7), as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ Standard Library, however, the declarations and definitions (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.5) of the namespace `std`.

Further to this, qualifying names with `std::` helps to avoid collisions - you know exactly what you're getting if you fully qualify it. If you're really going to do `using namespace std` or `using std::something`, at least do it in as minimal a scope as you can.

Answer (score 8):

In C++11, for the C headers that are explicitly named in the C++ standard, the following holds:

- An implementation is **required** for the <foo.h> versions to add them in the global namespace, and **allowed** to add them to the `std::` namespace.
- An implementation is **required** for the <cfoo> versions to add them in the `std::` namespace, and **allowed** to add them to the global namespace.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for wrapping things in the `std` namespace in the `<cstdint>` header is to avoid name collisions, which are quite unpleasant when they happen. However, in this case, it is very unlikely that the types will be found somewhere else. So I would use `<stdint.h>`, especially because this feature was introduced in `C` before it was added to `C++`, and hence the `<stdint.h>` header is older than `<cstdint>`, and therefore available in older compilers.

If you have decided that you want these names in the global namespace, you should also prefer `<stdint.h>` to `<cstdint>` followed by `using namespace std`, as the latter will dump all the other `std` stuff from other `<cfoo>` headers yhou have included into the global namspace too, which you probably do not want, as many other standard names are much more collision-prone than the likes of uint8_t.

Answer (score 2):

Include `<cstdint>` and use `std::` or include `<stdint.h>` to use unqualified type names. There are some platforms (e.g. QNX SDP 6.6) on which `<cstdint>` doesn't declare those types in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

My personal style is to always fully qualify names so it is clear where they come from. That is, I would use `std::uint8_t`. That is, I would include `<cstdint>` and use qualified names.

That said, note that use of `std::uint8_t` is only indicated if you really mean to use a type with *exactly* 8 bits. If the platform you are running your code on doesn't have such a type, e.g., because it uses 9 bit units as its basic entity, the program is supposed not to compile. If you want to use the smallest `unsigned` with 8 bits available, you want to use `uint_least8_t`.