# putting function inside a namespace breaks use of std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I have written a function that does the element-wise square root of a `std::vector<double>`

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
namespace pcif {
    std::vector<double> sqrt(const std::vector<double>& d) {
        std::vector<double> r;
        r.reserve(d.size());
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < r.size(); ++i) {
            r.push_back(sqrt(d[i]));
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

I am getting the error (all pointing to the `r.push_back` line):

- cannot convert from 'const _Ty' to 'const std::vector<double,std::allocator>'
- error C2664: 'std::vector<double,std::allocator> pcif::sqrt(const std::vector<double,std::allocator> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const _Ty' to 'const std::vector<double,std::allocator> &'
- Constructor for class 'std::vector<double,std::allocator>' is declared 'explicit'

If I remove the namespace, it all compiles with no dramas.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

I am working in Visual Studio 2019, C++17.

.

Follow-up question:

Using the fully qualified `std::sqrt()` solves this. Why did it work in my original case with no namespace? I can't just call `vector<double>`, why can I call `sqrt`?

Comment: Change `sqrt(d[i])` to `std::sqrt(d[i])`.  Otherwise you are trying to call your own `sqrt` function recursively (with the wrong type of argument).

Comment: Thanks. Why does this happen? I can't call just plain `vector<double>`, I need to qualify it with the namespace; why is `sqrt` different?

Comment: Because you called your function `sqrt`, so this name is in your scope.

Comment: @0x5453 your commen t doen't explain why it compile fine without `namespace pcif`

Comment: Overloading applies to names defined in the same scope. When your `sqrt` is defined in the global namespace it competes with the various `sqrt` functions in the standard library, which are also in the global namespace. When you define it inside a namespace and call it from inside that namespace there are no other overloads to consider, so you get an error.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I recommend you look into [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), as that will in a short simple call simplify your function (reduce it to three statements).

Comment: https://youtu.be/b5Kbzgx1w9A?t=1049 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, you should explicitly call `::sqrt()` (or from `std` namespace, `std::sqrt()`) instead, otherwise you are recursively calling your own `sqrt()` function with the wrong arguments.

The reason is that in the global namespace, there already exists a matching function called `sqrt()` (that's why it worked outside of the `pcif` namespace).
Once you are inside the `pcif` namespace, there are no other `sqrt()` overloads defined except the one you are writing, hence the recursion with the wrong arguments (Overloads are looked up in the same scope).
To solve this, you can explicitly call either the function of the global namespace `::sqrt()` or the one defined in the `std` namespace `std::sqrt()`.

Moreover, you should also change your loop condition from `i < r.size()` to `i < d.size()` instead, since `r` is empty.
Keep in mind that `reserve(n)` does not change the size of the container, it only allocates the necessary space for being able to store at least `n` elements without the need of reallocations (i.e. only the capacity is changed).
You may be interested to have a look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

Comment: Ta a lot. I've made that change to `d.size()`.

Comment: @masher I edited the question with the explanation about why it worked outside of the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that due to overload resolution, in the *call expression* `sqrt(d[i])`, the name `sqrt` refers to the same function that you're in. And since the type of the argument `d[i]` doesn't match with the type of the parameter `d` of the custom defined function, you get the mentioned error.

To **solve** this, you can **qualify** the name `sqrt` with `std::` in the call expression `sqrt(d[i])` so that it looks like:

```
namespace pcif {
    std::vector<double> sqrt(const std::vector<double>& d) {
        std::vector<double> r;
        r.reserve(d.size());
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < d.size(); ++i) {
//----------------------vvv--------------------> std:: added here
            r.push_back(std::sqrt(d[i]));
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

By using `std::` we're saying to the compiler that look in the **`std` namespace** for a function named `sqrt`.

Comment: Without the namespace, I can just call `sqrt`. Why don't I have to use `std::sqrt` all of the time? I can't just make a bare call to `vector<double`, I need to use  `std::vector<double`

Comment: @masher Because there is already a `sqrt` available in the global namespace. You can read more about it [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/).

Comment: If you're including <cmath> (as opposed to <math.h>) you have to use std::sqrt. If you use ::sqrt you're relying on undefined behaviour.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb It is unspecified behavior and not undefined behavior. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129945/use-types-in-cstdint-with-or-without-namespace).

Comment: @masher See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129945/use-types-in-cstdint-with-or-without-namespace) for your follow up(edited) question.